# Converting procedural code to OO

Tags: ruby

I have noticed a common pattern in my Ruby projects. Here is an example.

```
def collect_reverses b
  a = []
  b.each do |element|
    a << element.reverse
  end
  a
end
```

This particular example is stripped down to the bare essentials. Usually the code inside of the loop is more complicated.

The pattern described works. However, the procedural nature of this pattern is in stark contrast with the object oriented nature of the rest of the code.

Is there a cleaner/more OO method to accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (also known as `map`):

```
def collect_reverses(a)
  a.collect(&:reverse)
end
```

Comment: While this is a great style suggestion, this doesn't seem to address the OP's question. There's nothing more OO about this code than the OP's.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: true, I was addressing OP's question of "is there a cleaner... method to accomplish the same task".  What would be your answer to the question?

Comment: Probably the OP mistook OO and functional?

Comment: I was looking for OO, but cleaner was more important.